# TKinter - buttons not in a row?

Tags: python, tkinter

i try to bring those 2 buttons i a line under the dropboxes -

[image]

But as you can see in the picture - the button are not in the same line.
This is part of my code where i am setting the grid for the output:

```
myB = Button(root,text="Generate",padx=20,pady=10,command=show)
myB2 = Button(root,text="Reset",padx=20,pady=10,command=reset)

drop.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=2)
drop2.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=2)
drop3.grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan=2)
myB.grid(row=3,column=0)
myB2.grid(row=4,column=1)
```

Any ideas why this is not working as expected?

Comment: because `myB2` is in row 4 instead of row 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to match your image the code needs to look like this.

```py
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight = 1)

myB = Button(root, text = "Generate", padx = 20, pady = 10, command = show)
myB2 = Button(root, text = "Reset", padx = 20, pady = 10, command = reset)

# sticky needed for resizing with window
drop.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.NSEW)
drop2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.NSEW)
drop3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.NSEW)
# This will make buttons 'float' otherwise un-rem sticky
myB.grid(row = 3, column = 0) #, sticky = tk.NSEW)
myB2.grid(row = 3, column = 1) #, sticky = tk.NSEW)
```

Comment: The problem of OP is *"the button are not in the same line"* as shown in the image.  @Art has already identified the cause in his comment.

Comment: Without the `row/column configure` and the inclusion of `sticky` the code supplied does not match the image.

Comment: Yes it can by using something like `drop.config(width=60, bd=5)`.

Comment: Yep that could be another way but it would have to be applied to every drop object.